# Is there a standard behind the default system accounts in a linux system like fedora or debian?

Tags: security, linux, user-accounts

By *system accounts* I mean the ones that comes preinstalled with the system, for example `nobody`, `daemon` and `bin`. I know these tend to vary depending to the distro and the installed packages, but:

is there a standard set of system accounts?
What are the security implications behind these accounts (i.e. why run something as user `nobody`)?

Where do I read about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much specified anywhere.  You can read a little bit at the [Linux Standard Base Core Spec](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/lsb.shtml) and specifically [about users here](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/tocusersgroups.html).

The general reason for different accounts is a basic security premise.  Restrict functions to a single user only, so that user can't interact with unrelated stuff.  You don't want a user to be able to reboot the server just because you used the same user ID / group for starting and stopping the system as you did for managing print queues.